# Default serializer render options in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, actioncontroller, active-model-serializers

I am using [Active Model Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) in a rails project and have a `user` object that needs to be passed in from the controller to the serializer like this:

```
# Note the 'user:' option that will be accessible inside
# the serializer with @options[:user]
def show
render json: @some_object, user: current_user
end

def index
render json: SomeObject.all, user: current_user
end
```

This is good enough for what I am trying to do, but it is not very DRY and results in `render` statements that are littered with options. When those options change, I need to go back and manually remove/modify them across all actions.

My question is: **Is there a way to set a list of default options for a `render` call at the controller level, instead of manually putting the options in every single controller action?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished by adding this method to your controller:

```
def default_serializer_options  
  {user: current_user}  
end
```

You can then access it from within the serializer via `options[:user]`

Comment: This has been _removed_ in 0.10.x (not deprecated)